# Why does the changebar package create a page full of "spsp" and how can this be fixed?

Tags: table-of-contents

> This question from Feb 25 '14 at 17:20 is about the [changebar](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/changebar) package version 2005/09/18 v3.5c.
> That version has a bug, see explanation and fix in answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162383.
> In official package version 2018/03/09 v3.6c the bug has been fixed.

To place bars into the "Table of Contents" I use the changebar package, version 2005/09/18 v3.5c, and compile the document with pdflatex (TeXLive 2013, updated 2014/02/25) at least four times. (With `latex`, dvi output, the issue does not occur.) This works OK, but it also creates a page full of "spsp" (presumably from small point-lengthes) after the last page of the document ([known problem](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.german/21010)). Using the [afterpage](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) and [atbegshi](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi) packages I can get rid of that page by placing `\afterpage{\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}}` before `\end{document}`, but that neither tells me what is wrong nor how to correct it.

The MWE is a bit longer, because a "critical toc length" is needed for the error to occur. Even a lot of `\cbend\pagebreak\cbstart` in the toc (to prevent the changebars to span a pagebreak) did not solve the problem. Increasing `\cb@maxpoint` neither solved the problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[c5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[color]{changebar}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cbgreen}{%
\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{toc}{\string\cbend{}}}
\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{toc}{\string\cbcolor{green}}}
\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{toc}{\string\cbstart}}}
\newcommand{\cbred}{%
\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{toc}{\string\cbend{}}}
\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{toc}{\string\cbcolor{red}}}
\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{toc}{\string\cbstart}}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{w}
\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{toc}{\string\cbcolor{red}}}
\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{toc}{\string\cbstart}}
\chapter{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\part{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\section{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\section{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\section{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\section{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\section{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\section{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\section{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\section{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\section{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\section{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\section{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\section{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\section{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\section{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\section{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\section{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\section{w}
\part{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\subsubsection{w}
\paragraph{w}
\paragraph{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{toc}{\string\newpage}}
\part{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\part{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\part{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{toc}{\string\newpage}}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\part{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\cbred
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\section{w}
\cbgreen
\chapter{w}
\section{w}
\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{toc}{\string\cbend{}}}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Comment: I see it with TeXLive 2010 and `pdflatex`, but not with `latex` (dvi output).

Comment: there seems to be a bug in the `changebar` package. A trace just before `\end{document}` gives `\cb@pdfxy #1#2#3#4#5->\cb@@findpdfpoint {#1}{#2}\ifnum #3=\cb@pdfx \relax \ifnu
m #4=\cb@pdfy \relax \ifdim #5=\cb@pdfz \relax \else \cb@error \fi \else \cb@er
ror \fi \else \cb@error \fi ` but when it does the `\ifnum` `\cb@pdfx` expands to `4531218sp` and `\cb@pdfy` expands to `29548831sp`. No doubt the `spsp` come from that.

Comment: @jfbu: Thanks! +1 for your answer and accepted. Could you please move your comment into your answer? I think this is essential information to the "Why?" part of my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem appears to be solved with the following set-up in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
\def\cb@checkPdfxy#1#2#3#4#5{%
\cb@@findpdfpoint{#1}{#2}%
\ifdim#3sp=\cb@pdfx\relax      % <<-- original has \ifnum#3=\cb@pdfx
\ifdim#4sp=\cb@pdfy\relax      % <<-- original has \ifnum#4=\cb@pdfy
\ifdim#5=\cb@pdfz\relax
\else
\cb@error
\fi
\else
\cb@error
\fi
\else
\cb@error
\fi
}}
\makeatother
\usepackage[color]{changebar}
```

Please note that the order of things must be as above.

Indeed adding `\tracingmacros1` just before `\end{document}` and examining the log one finds a  `\let\cb@pdfxy\cb@checkPdfxy` where `\cb@checkPdfxy` is as above except that it uses `\ifnum#3=\cb@pdfx`, `\ifnum#4=\cb@pdfy`, but when this is later expanded `\cb@pdfx` and `\cb@pdfy` turn out to be some number followed by `sp`.

I chose to transform the test in an `\ifdim` but another way would be possibly to modify the part of the code defining the scratch macros `\cb@pdfx` and `\cb@pdfy` and avoid the extra `sp` (one sees in the log that the `sp` is added by the code). Not having read anything else from the `changebar` code I don't know if this alternative would break something else.

The patched macro is put in `\AtEndDocument` before the loading of the package in order to have the `\let\cb@pdfxy\cb@checkPdfxy`  executed after it.

There should be a way to do a patch using `etoolbox` but I noticed in the doc of `changebar` that `\cb@checkPdfxy` was defined as a `\gdef` inside some other macro (perhaps an option processing) and I did not investigate more. Anyway, with this the infamous page of `spsp`'s is gone.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see it with the current TeXLive 2013 and using

```
\immediate\write\@auxout{...}
```

or use

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\cbend{}}
```

It works with the `dvips` driver and the sequence `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` but not with the `pdftex` driver.

Comment: try to run the document with `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

Comment: `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` would work indeed, but I need pdflatex instead of latex for the original (not MWE) document (and `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` does not tell me _what_ is going wrong).