# strange page at end of multiple chapter document

Tags: formatting

The last page of my thesis looks like this. Has anyone ever seen anything like this?

When I click on it in texshop, it brings me to the tex.aux file and I see stuff like this:

> \cb@pdfxy{347}{320}{5328321}{10094626}{-21.96626pt}

I don't even know how to tag this question!

[image]

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: Nope the whole document compiles fine. This is just the last page.

Comment: All I can suggest is that you create a copy, and then remove sections until it compiles without error. Then narrow it down systematically. Personally I use a binary approach. Remove half, and determine which half is the problem. Halve that problem part and determine which is the problem, ... That way you very quickly narrow it down. Alternatively since it's at the end, you could try a bottom-up approach.

Comment: Oh yes, do you have the "spsp" string anywhere in your file?

Comment: Delete the `.aux` file and recompile a couple of times. Does the problem persist?

Comment: `\cb@pdfxy` is from the `changebar` package.  Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/162332/15925 help?